Why is LM2852YMXAX-3.3 not working?
This is my schematic, I want 5V as input and 3.3V as output, am I giving the wrong Enable pin?


Some issues I see with your design. (There might be more.)
(1) Instead of connecting SGND to SS, you have to connect it to GNDA.

(2) For your requirements, the output filter should be L11 = 15..22 uH, C19 = 68..100uF.

Source: Datasheet
(3) PVIN must always be equal to or less than AVIN (quote from the dataseet 7.3.1).
In your case, PVIN is greater than AVIN, if only slightly. I would short R3 to make them both the same.
(4) Make sure that SNS is connected as close to the output voltage as possible.

The most likely cause is using the SS and SGND pins incorrectly by tying them together.
Another cause may be the exposed pad being left unconnected.
The enable is also not connected to AVIN but to PVIN. This should not be a huge issue as your 5V input is almost same. Technically not correct.
The used inductor and output capacitor are not from list of typical example values.
The inductor should be 15..22 uH and capacitor much more in range of 68..100 uF.
